# Base url in background image joomla

Tags: joomla

I am creating a template and someone has created the orignal slider using

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(../images/slider/bg1.jpg)">
```

My question is I am using Joomla to create this template how do i echo in the above html so that I can output the full url of site for at min its not finding the image.

```
<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
JUri::base()
```

accepting an optional parameter (true or false) 
to include the protocol and site name.